# Getting a very short visitor visa for the US as an Indian citizen

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas

I'm an Indian national and I have a friend in USA who got stuck and I wanna go and get her. The thing is I can't show bank balance, as I don't have any, but I have credit cards worth 5000 USD and I have no intention of staying in the US. I just wanna get in, collect my friend and get back on the same day itself.

I know the consulate officer would reject my visa due to insufficient funds, but I'm not planning to stay and it's just one day visit, and it's like life saving emergency. Would I be given a chance to explain to consulate officer? Any idea to get visa.

My friend is having H4 visa and she can't sponsor me. I've tried for sponsorship from my friend, but he says he has already sponsored enough people for his quota.

Is there any chance that I can get a visa, at least 12 hour visa would do fine, but there seems to be no such thing. Can anybody suggest a solution for this situation ?

Comment: Call the Embassy and explain your situation (and your friend's dire need).  IF there is a way to be issued an emergency visa, they will tell you how to go about it.

Comment: Have you tried phoning the Indian Embassy in the USA, and explaining your friend's problem? They might be able to help your friend without you needing to go there

Comment: Unless she's a child who can't travel alone even with the assistance of an airline I don't see any reason for you to travel to the US.  And if it is such a child why exactly the H1 holder for whom she's a dependant isn't able to send her back to India.  I think you're trying for a bad solution in with a solvable problem.

Comment: She's fleeing an abusive relationship? So, no access to funds but she does have access to her passport? Because otherwise, how is she going to leave the country?

Comment: Yes she is fleeing an abusive relationship, she is in shelter now. She has some money to book her ticket, but she is afraid she might be stopped by her husband.  She got preliminary protection, but couldn't get final protection, bcoz of her kids.  Her husband wouldn't let her leave with the kids, easily, she doesn't know anybody out there and she's got medically sick. She's been to hospital every week. So if i could get there,I can get her with the help of police.

Comment: She filed for divorce in India, but her parents withdrew the case and forced her to USA. Since she can't get final protection, she don't wanna file divorce there in USA, here in India, she can get help from her relatives and friends.

Comment: Sounds like you need to file a report with the local police, and get a lawyer. Get her the protection and authority she needs. You don't need to be in the US to do those things. Then, once she has it, use you credit cards to buy her (and her kids), flights home

Comment: She tried for the protection, but she wasn't able to, judge warned her husband and didn't give her protection. Judge asked her to stay in shelter until she feels it's okay to move in with him. But she wants a divorce. She is afraid to go alone to meet lawyer. She doesn't wanna go alone in cabs or anything. It's because she's like locked in her house all the time there, she was never ever let out alone. Now all of a sudden, after her experiences, she doesn't wanna go out alone anywhere. So only i want to get there.

Comment: Why would the officer reject you for funds? You have to show you have enough for the day - if you've got a flight out, and have enough for say food and transport for the day (a large credit card limit is likely sufficient), there's no reason to assume you'd be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

The situation in question sounds like something to be solved with the local police department rather than in-person, however you could still try applying for a visa. Your options are:

- Apply for a single-entry tourist US visa for 3 days, book the hotels and flights. Assuming you can satisfy the normal visa requirements you shouldn't have any troubles.
- Book a flight *through* the US with a 24 hour layover and apply for a transit visa. US airports don't have a sterile transit zone, so once you've passed immigration nothing stops you from visiting your friend. One good country to fly to would be Ecuador, since it doesn't require Indian citizens to apply for a visa.